# Selecting active layer in Photoshop ... with keyboard

Tags: photoshop

I know cmd+click on layer's thumbnail will select it, but ...

Is there a way to select an active layer with a keyboard? I can't seem to find that option in the menu, so can't assign a shortcut for it ... but maybe I'm just blind.

PS I know it's NYE ... I must get a life

Comment: sorry guys, what I mean is to select layer's shape - just like after cmd+click on a layer's thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

it's actually pretty easy : 
Ctrl + A / Cmd + A

Comment: thx for answer but .. that selects all the layers ... I want to select single layer, the one currently active

Comment: put some screenshot i don't see what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Within the keyboard shortcut menu you can see that the "select entire layer" is not an available option (as you stated)

The CTRL/ CMD + A mentioned above selects all of the items on the CURRENT ACTIVE LAYER (not ALL layers as you have stated)

..I am not sure what you want to do outside of this?